# Duplicate Variable error in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am writing this trigger and am running into the error of duplicate variable I (attempt to recreate the variable with type integer) error. This particular line is where the error is triggering.

```
for(Integer I = 0,  I < lstNumValue.size(); i++)
```

I'm a bit stuck, anything I can to adjust. Trigger code below.

Hope it helps.

```
trigger ProductDonationsSummary on Product_Donations__c (before insert) 
{  
Map<Integer, String> mapNumValueAndFieldLabel = new Map<Integer,String>();
for(Product_Donations__c pd : Trigger.new){
//null checkers for the field and adding the number value as key and the string message as the value if its not null/blank/zero
IF(pd.Total_LettersTally__c != null && pd.Total_LettersTally__c != '' && pd.Integer.valueOf(Total_LettersTally__c) != 0)
{
    mapNumValueAndFieldLabel.put(Integer.valueOf(pd.Total_LettersTally__c), pd.Total_LettersTally__c + ' letters');
}

IF(pd.Gators__c != null && pd.Gators__c != '' && Integer.valueOf(pd.Gators__c) != 0)
{
    mapNumValueAndFieldLabel.put(Integer.valueOf(pd.Gators__c), pd.Gators__c + ' Gators');
}

IF(pd.Paracords__c != null && pd.Paracords__c != '' && Integer.valueOf(pd.Paracords__c) != 0)
{
    mapNumValueAndFieldLabel.put(Integer.valueOf(pd.Paracords__c), pd.Paracords__c + ' paracord bracelets');
}
//and so on for other fields....

//Proceed further only if either of the fields have non zero values 
if(mapNumValueAndFieldLabel.values().size() > 0)
{
    List<Integer> lstNumValue = new List<integer> ();
    lstNumValue.addAll(mapNumValueAndFieldLabel.keyset());

    //Sort the Values (by default SFDC sorts it in ascending order)
    lstNumValue.sort();
    String strMessage = '';
    //Iterating through the sorted Integer list in reverse order (descending) to get the final String message from    //the map 
    for(Integer I = 0,  I < lstNumValue.size(); i++)
    {
        strMessage += mapNumValueAndFieldLabel.get(lstNumValue(i)) + ', ';
    }
 }
  //create new long text area field to store your string values
    pd.Your_New_Long_Text_Area_field__c = strMessage;
   }

}
```

Comment: Post your entire trigger please....Or double check that you do not have a loop using the variable I inside another loop using the variable I. Also, it would be helpful if you post the sniper from the debug log showing the error. As posted I do not see another variable named I so.....

Comment: Also, sometimes a variable conflicts with a system variable (undocumented bug), so try changing the variable to x or z and see if it works.

Comment: You have a comma in the loop declaration instead of a semicolon.

Comment: the removal of the comma for semi colon helps. Many thanks.